# iptables rule explanation

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I was wondering, could somebody help me to understand/explain what this iptables rule does exactly?

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW  -m limit --limit 5/m --limit-burst 7 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "Dropped"
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

Thanks

Comment: Krypton78 - you're welcome. The appropriate thing to do is, when you're satisfied with one of the answers you've received, mark it as "accepted". If none of the answers are to your liking, then provide additional clarification in the comments of that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are two rules there. I'll go through each of them.

I believe the following is accurate:

### Rule 1

```
-A INPUT
```

Add this rule to the INPUT chain

```
-i eth0
```

This rule applies only to packets arriving via eth0

```
-p tcp
```

This rule applies only to tcp traffic

```
! --syn
```

Match packets that don't have the SYN bit set.

```
-m state
```

Track the state of this connection.

```
-state NEW
```

This only applies to new connections.

```
-m limit
```

Invoke the rate limiter.

```
--limit 5/m
```

Limit matches to 5 per minute.

```
--limit-burst 7
```

Set maximum number of initial matched packets to 7.

```
-j LOG
```

Write this entry to the iptables log.

```
--log-level
```

Set log verbosity to 4.

```
--log-prefix "Dropped"
```

Prefix the log message with "Dropped".

### Rule 2

```
-A INPUT
```

Add this rule to the INPUT chain

```
-i eth0
```

This rule applies only to packets arriving via eth0

```
-p tcp
```

This rule applies only to tcp traffic

```
! --syn
```

This rule does not apply to SYN packets.

```
-m state
```

Track the state of this connection.

```
--state NEW
```

This only applies to new connections.

```
-j DROP
```

DROP packets that match the above conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Log bad tcp packages(5 per minute and burst 7) and drop it